# Simple C++ Program Compiled without Optimization by GCC doesn't Generate Expected Results

Tags: c++, gcc

Today when I tried to compile a very simple C++ program using GCC7, I met a very strange problem: the program didn't add any elements to a vector in the constructor, when compiled without optimization (e.g. -O0/-Og) by the GCC 7.2.1 from Devtoolset-7 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. Only when the optimization switch was added (e.g. -O/-O1/-O2/...), the compiled binary can generated expected results. But why is this happening?

By the way:

1. without optimization, the binaries compiled by GCC 7.2.1 on RHEL7 and GCC 7.3.0 on Mac (Homebrew version) behaved differently: the former didn't add any elements, while the latter add 2 elements.
2. clang doesn't have this problem no matter the optimization is turned on or not)

The code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class Container
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> elements;

public:

    Container() {}

    Container(std::size_t n)
    {
        std::cout << "Creating " << n << " elements:";
        for(int i; i<n; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << " " << i+1;
            elements.push_back(i+1);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    Container(Container& c) : elements{c.elements} {}

    Container(Container&& c) : elements{std::move(c.elements)} {}

    virtual ~Container() noexcept {}

    Container& operator=(const Container& c)
    {
        if(this != &c)
        {
            elements = c.elements;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Container& operator=(Container&& c)
    {
        if(this != &c)
        {
            elements = std::move(c.elements);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Container has " << elements.size() << " elements:" << '\n';
        for(auto it=elements.cbegin(); it!=elements.cend(); ++it)
        {
            if(it == elements.cbegin()) std::cout << *it;
            else std::cout << ", " << *it;
        }
        if(elements.size()>0) std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

Container makeContainer()
{
    std::cout << "Inside makeContainer()" << '\n';

    std::cout << "Before:" << '\n';
    Container c(3);
    c.print();

    std::cout << "Temporary:" << '\n';
    Container c_tmp(3);
    c_tmp.print();
    c = c_tmp;

    std::cout << "After:" << '\n';
    c.print();
    return c;
};

int main()
{
    Container c = makeContainer();
    std::cout << "Inside main()" << '\n';
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Inside makeContainer()
Before:
Creating 3 elements: 1 2 3
Container has 3 elements:
1, 2, 3
Temporary:
Creating 3 elements: 1 2 3
Container has 3 elements:
1, 2, 3
After:
Container has 3 elements:
1, 2, 3
Inside main()
Container has 3 elements:
1, 2, 3
```

Actual output:

```
Inside makeContainer()
Before:
Creating 3 elements:
Container has 0 elements:
Temporary:
Creating 3 elements:
Container has 0 elements:
After:
Container has 0 elements:
Inside main()
Container has 0 elements:
```

Comment: If you reduce this to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will get more attention.

Comment: RHEL 7 is at GCC 4.8. You must be using devtoolset?

Comment: This is almost exactly what should be in a question. The only fault is a little more reducing of the problem would have exposed the bug and the need for the question question would have been eliminated.

Comment: Yes the GCC7 is brought by devtoolset-7. I should have removed some redundant codes before posting. Thanks for reminding!

Comment: Please correct that in your question.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not assign a value to a variable its state is indeterminate.

In debug mode the compiler can put the value zero to initialize indeterminate values to help with debugging. But in release this extra unasked for initialization will not happen.

```
    for(int i; i<n; ++i)  // Here you have declared `i` but not initialized it.
```

As a result in release mode the value is probably larger than `n` and thus no elements are inserted.

Note: It is UB to read the value of an initialized variable (so your whole program can do anything).

Comment: Interestingly (not really) the OP reported the opposite results to the intuitive expectation you've described (w.r.t. debug vs release mode). But it doesn't really matter because you're spot on

Comment: Thanks Martin for spotting such an obvious bug! Couldn't believe myself still made such error. After using -Wall during compiling, these "trivial" things are immediately identified by compilers.